# Formal description of Coq’s termination checker

Tags: coq

Coq’s built-in termination checker accepts some rather intricate recursion patterns with functional values in data types, as shown by this example

```
Inductive Z_inf_branch_tree : Set :=
  Z_inf_leaf : Z_inf_branch_tree
| Z_inf_node : Z→(nat→Z_inf_branch_tree)→Z_inf_branch_tree.

Fixpoint n_sum_all_values (n:nat)(t:Z_inf_branch_tree){struct t} : Z :=
(match t with
| Z_inf_leaf ⇒ 0
| Z_inf_node v f ⇒ v + sum_f n (fun x:nat ⇒ n_sum_all_values n (f x)) end ).
```

(taken from from Chapter 7.3.5.2 here https://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/CoqArt/coqartF.pdf).

I am looking for a formal description of the termination checker at work here, in order to reimplement it in a different system? Is it written down somewhere accessible?

Answer (score 8):

Lennard Gäher has implemented Coq's guard checker in Coq on top of MetaCoq as part of a lecture project I advised here:

https://github.com/lgaeher/metacoq/blob/guarded/guarded/guardchecker.v

It has lots of comments and examples is the most accessible description I know of, the other two existing descriptions I am aware of being the comments in the OCaml code of Coq's implementation and [this slide set](https://coq.inria.fr/files/adt-2fev10-barras.pdf) by Bruno Barras, both of which served as sources for Lennard's code.

Lennard's code turns Coq's guardedness checker off to avoid making some functions structurally recursive, and thus there are no proofs about it. In principle it should however be possible to turn everything into "proper" Coq functions with some work and then prove the properties postulated in MetaCoq [here](https://github.com/MetaCoq/metacoq/blob/coq-8.14/template-coq/theories/Typing.v#L548).

Comment: Thank you Yannick, this is very helpful!

Comment: I noticed the code says "I don't currently understand the exact reasons why restrictions of subterm info flow through dependent matches is needed in some cases. I have documented what is restricted, but not why it is needed."

I believe the source of these restrictions is https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/4f15ea63061158bca1/dev/doc/critical-bugs#L426-L435, https://github.com/coq/coq/commit/9b272a86, https://github.com/coq/coq/commit/ccd7546cd, https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2013-12/msg00119.html, and https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2013-12/msg00114.html